# Jquery Onclick div with class and alert if clicked on inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html, onclick

If I am clicking on 'See me', it should alert me 'see me'.
I could do this as $('div').click... and it's working fine too. But I think it's better to do with the container div. Because the entire page is a long page and the function will run whereever I click if I use div for onclick.

```
<div class="directFilter">
    <div class="boxWithRightArrow seeMe">See me</div>
    <div class="boldFont filterHeader">Sort By</div>
    <div class="boxWithRightArrow borderTop bestClick">Best click</div>
    <div class="boxWithRightArrow intermediateTime">Intermediate time</div>
    <div class="boxWithRightArrow shortestTime">Shortest time</div>
    <div class="boxWithRightArrow iPreferred">I preferred</div>
</div>


$('.directFilter').click(function() {

        alert($(this).attr('class')); //alerts directFilter 

            if ( $( this ).hasClass( "seeMe" ) ) {
                alert("see me");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("bestClick")) {
                alert("b click");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("intermediateTime")) {
                alert("itime");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("shortestTime")) {
                alert("s time");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("iPreferred")) {
                alert("i pre");
            }
}
    );
```

**JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/e2L7s/**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use event.target to identify the source of event. then You need to use html() or text() like `$(event.target).html()` or `$(event.target).text()` to get the inner contents of element.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2L7s/1/)**

```
$('.directFilter').click(function(event) {
        alert($(event.target).html()); //alerts directFilter 
});
```

If you have unique work to do in each if then you will need to use event.target as a source object identification in the condition.

Comment: Great !
It works fine. 
Thanks :)

I can set this as the answer(the tick mark) only after 8minutes !!

Comment: This is what i wanted : alert($(event.target).hasClass('seeMe'));

Comment: Then what about other conditions?

Comment: Yea. For all div i need. I will do. One doubt : Which is the best way ? Your post or ProllyGeek's post ?

Comment: Can't you figure out the no.of lines of code of Adil and Prolly

Comment: @FurquanKhan , i think the number of lines in the code will be same, if i wrote the IF condition. Please see my last answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
    // use this if you want limit clicks in .directFilter only
    // $(document).on('click','.directFilter',function(e)

    $this = $(e.target);
    alert($this.text())
});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/e2L7s/7/

```
$('.directFilter').children().click(function() {

      //  alert($(this).attr('class')); //alerts directFilter 

            if ( $( this ).hasClass( "seeMe" ) ) {
                alert("see me");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("bestClick")) {
                alert("b click");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("intermediateTime")) {
                alert("itime");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("shortestTime")) {
                alert("s time");
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("iPreferred")) {
                alert("i pre");
            }
}
    );
```

why using so many IFs ?!

Answer (score 1):

Team,

**Which is the best way ?**

http://jsfiddle.net/smilyface/e2L7s/18/

> ```
> $('.directFilter').click(function(event) {
>         if($(event.target)....
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/e2L7s/7/

```
$('.directFilter').children().click(function() {
if ( $( this )....
```

Comment: first one event.target